# Read and parse .cer file

Tags: php, ssl

I have a certificate (.cer) I have to read de basic information of the certificate, like expiration date.

I wrote this code in php

```
class FirmaElectronica {
    public function abrirCertificado( $path ){

        $cert_content = file_get_contents( $path );


        $res = openssl_x509_read( $cert_content );

        $data = openssl_x509_parse( $res );
        var_dump( $data );
    }
}

$firma = new FirmaElectronica();
$firma->abrirCertificado('gohl881206rga.cer');
```

But always get this warning and an empty array of data

```
PHP Warning:  openssl_x509_read(): supplied parameter cannot be coerced into an X509 certificate!
```

If I execute this command i get all the certificate data

```
openssl x509 -in gohl881206rga.cer -noout -text -inform der
```

What is the correct way to get the certificate data with php?

Comment: Are you sure the file is being read? What does `var_dump(file_get_contents('gohl881206rga.cer'));` give you? When opening files you should always use the full path. Relative paths are difficult to work with if you do not know what they are relative to.

Comment: Yeah I try the `var_dump` of the file and I get a string with the information but with a strange encoding, I try to detect the encoding with `mb_detect_encoding` and changing to utf-8 with `mb_convert_encoding($cert_content, 'UTF-8');` but any way I get the same result.

Comment: Since you have `-inform der` in your `openssl` command, I assume it's a binary file and you don't want to try treating it like text. Have you tried running from command line? E.g. `php -r "print_r(openssl_x509_parse(openssl_x509_read(file_get_contents('/full/path/to/gohl881206rga.cer'))));"`

Comment: I just try it, and I get the same error `PHP Warning:  openssl_x509_read(): supplied parameter cannot be coerced into an X509 certificate! in Command line code on line 1`

Answer (score 5):

Using [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/x509/intro.html)..

```
<?php
include('File/X509.php');

$x509 = new File_X509();
$cert = $x509->loadX509('...');

echo $cert['tbsCertificate']['validity']['notBefore'] . "\r\n";
echo $cert['tbsCertificate']['validity']['notAfter'];
```

If that doesn't work can you post the actual cert you're trying to get this info from?

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert to `.pem` first in order to read and parse the `.cer` file:

```php
// 1. read the file
$storagePath = storage_path('cer/certificate.cer');
$certificateContent = file_get_contents($storagePath);

// 2. convert the .cer to .pem
$certificateCApemContent = '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----'.PHP_EOL
            .chunk_split(base64_encode($cert), 64, PHP_EOL)
            .'-----END CERTIFICATE-----'.PHP_EOL;

// 3. parse the content
$certificateParsed = openssl_x509_parse($certificateCApemContent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. To solve this you need to ensure you have the private key for cer (or pem).

to answer

1 export cert AND key to .p12

On OSX e.g.: open keychain -> select your cert AND the including key -> ctrl-click export -> export 2 Objects.

2 convert your cert:

```
 openssl pkcs12 -in cert.p12 -out cert.pem -nodes -clcerts
```

3 to be safe

```
cat cert.pem
```

you should see something like:

```
Bag Attributes
    friendlyName: blablub
    localKeyID: SOME ID HERE
subject=/UID=(name)/CN=(a name)/OU=(a id)/C=(locale)
issuer=/C=(locale)/O=(auth)/OU=(authname)/CN=(name)
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
ABCD.....(cert here).....
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
Bag Attributes
    friendlyName: blubbla
    localKeyID: SOME ID HERE 
Key Attributes: <No Attributes>
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
AB....(key here)....
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

now you are ready to go with your original code without another lib in php:

```
 $cert_content = file_get_contents( $path );
 $res = openssl_x509_read( $cert_content );
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is outdated but i want to share a possible solution for this problem.

> First: i had the same issue. The certificate was correct and my PHP
>   code too.

I have found out that the problem was the formatting of the certificate. To solve this i created a function and editet the certificate correctly:

```
function createCertificate($cert) {

        $a = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n";
        $b = "\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----";

        $withoutFirsLine = substr($cert, strlen('-----BEGINCERTIFICATE-----'));

        $count = (strlen($withoutFirsLine) - strlen('-----ENDCERTIFICATE-----'));
        $withoutFirstAndLastLine = substr($withoutFirsLine, 0, $count);

        $withoutFirstAndLastLine = wordwrap($withoutFirstAndLastLine, 64, "\n", true);

        return $a.$withoutFirstAndLastLine . $b;

}
```

I hope i could help other people who has the same issue!